# Expression for angular momentum

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems

I wanted to derive an expression for angular momentum of a rigid body in the frame of a particle on the rigid body
I started out this way.
$$L=r x p  
=r x mv= m (r x v) = m (r x (w x r))=m( r^2(w)-(r.w)(r).$$  summation of this over all particles should give me the answer, but
now the issue is I don't know under what cases it reduces to the form Iw
also the r which I have used is from the point not from the axis.
My teacher told me it does so only for fixed axis rotation.
Also I  don't really know how to define an axis. If it is the locus of all centres of circles then why is it a straight line?  Please explain the cases when angular momentum reduces to $Iw$.

Comment: if you turn something, first just one point, than you have always an axes of rotation , if a second point is on the same rigid body it has the same axes. Try to turn any object and you see it.

Comment: FYI - Don't use `x` for the cross-product. It is confusing. Use `\times` which renders as $\times$. Similarly, don't use `.` for the dot-product, but rather `\cdot` which renders as $\cdot$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using vectors carefully might make it easier to answer your question.
\begin{equation}
\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p} = m\vec{r} \times \vec{v}.
\end{equation}
Since $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\vec{L} = m(r^2\vec{\omega} - \vec{r}(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\omega})),
\end{equation}
If the axis of rotation is such that $\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{r} = 0$, that is if the plane of rotation is always perpendicular to the axis of rotation you get the familiar expression
\begin{equation}
\vec{L} = mr^2\vec{\omega} = I\vec{\omega}.
\end{equation}
You may want to consult a book like Halliday and Resnick for an excellent explanation of this topic.

The vector $\vec{r}$ is the position of the particle with respect to (your choice of) origin and $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

### System of particles

Consider a rigid body as a system of particles, each of which is fixed on some rotating reference frame. Consider that the frame is rotating with rotational velocity $\vec{\omega}$ about the origin.

Each particle of mass $m_i$ has translational velocity $$\vec{v}_i= \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_i \tag{1}$$ where $\vec{r}_i$ is location of the particle at some time-slice.

Note that since $\vec{\omega}$ is shared among *all* the particles, the total translational momentum is zero if the center of mass is also at the origin

$$ \vec{p} = \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_i = \sum_i m_i ( \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}_i) = \vec{\omega} \times \underbrace{ \sum_i m_i \vec{r}_i}_{\text{defn. as }0} = \vec{0} \tag{2} $$

Now we look at total rotational momentum

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{L} & = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times (m_i \vec{v}_i) = \sum_i m_i ( \vec{r}_i \times( \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_i))= \\ & = \sum_i m_i \left( (\vec{r}_i \cdot \vec{r}_i) \vec{\omega} - \vec{r}_i ( \vec{r}_i \cdot \vec{\omega})  \right) = \\ &= \left[ \sum_i m_i \left( ( \vec{r}_i \cdot \vec{r}_i ) {\bf 1}_{3×3} - \vec{r}_i \odot \vec{r}_i \right) \right] \vec{\omega} = \\ & = {\rm I}\; \vec{\omega}  \end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

where $\cdot$ is the vector inner product (dot-product), $\odot$ is the vector outer product and ${\bf 1}_{3×3}$ is the identity matrix.

The above leads to the explicit definition of

$$ {\rm I} = \sum_i m_i \begin{vmatrix} y_i^2+z_i^2 & -x_i y_i & -x_i z_i 
\\ -x_i y_i & x_i^2+z_i^2 & -y_i z_i \\
-x_i z_i & -y_i z_i & x_i^2+y_i^2 \end{vmatrix} \tag{4} $$

You need the following linear algebra manipulations

- $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{a}^\intercal \boldsymbol{b}$
- $\boldsymbol{a} ( \boldsymbol{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{c}) = \boldsymbol{a} ( \boldsymbol{b}^\intercal \boldsymbol{c}) = (\boldsymbol{a} \boldsymbol{b}^\intercal) \boldsymbol{c} = (\boldsymbol{a} \odot \boldsymbol{b}) \boldsymbol{c} $